# Get top 100 words in a large file

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce

To get top 100 words in a small file, we can simply use a hashmap

```
  for each word in file
         hash(word)++;

    maxHeap(hash, 100)
```

If the file is extra-large, we can easily use MapReduce.

My question is, is the following pseudocode a right logic？

```
divide file into N chunks
   for each chunk
      hash(word)++;
   maxHeap(hash, 100)

merge the N chunks and get the final top 100.
```

Can we prove the final top 100 words coming from top 100 words in each chunk?

Comment: It turns out that you will find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541983/find-the-10-most-frequently-used-words-in-a-large-book?rq=1

Comment: You can not easily use MapReduce. It is more complicated. You have to precise first your constraints: you want to distribute the job on multiple computers ? with a central ? how do they talk ?

Comment: Your pseudocode used "word" without stating where it comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Analysis

Your algorithm is wrong because you assume the top words in the entire collection is equal to the sum of the top words in the individual chunks. Because you prune in each chunk you run the possibility of missing out on a better word.

**Correct Answer**
Collection: (cat,5)(dog,5)(moose,4)
Top2: (cat,dog)

**Your Sort**
Chunk1: (cat,2)(dog,4)(moose,4) => (dog,4)(moose,4)
Chunk2: (cat,3)(dog,1) => (cat,3)(dog,1)
Merge: (cat,3)(dog,5)(moose,4)
Top2: (dog,moose)

**(dog,moose) != (cat,dog)**

Using a hash map also might not be the right way to go. If we're dealing with a lot of data and the words are very sparse and unique the hash map won't fit in main memory. Depending on the sensitivity of the data, there could also be hash collisions.

---

### **External Merge Sort**

It might be better to divide the file into N chunks. For each chunk you would perform your count and then sort it alphabetically so that the file contains (word, count) pairs. And then you could perform an N way merge over all of the files. The files are merged alphabetically (i.e. A file with a word at the head that is alphabetically before another file's head should be advanced first). When done correctly you can add a word's count from all of the files to get it's total count. As you're performing this merge you can keep track of the X top words.

The external merge sort algorithm is outlined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: how much does it cost to do that, with big file, and many words ? the question is not to sort every words, just keep the top 100 .

Answer (score 0):

No,

Think this situation
Chunk 1: AABBBCCC
Chunk 2: AADDDEEE

Chunk 1 get max 2 character =>  Bx3 and Cx3.
Chunk 2 get max 2 character =>  Dx3 and Ex3.

We miss "A" character. (Ax4)

Pseudo code should be this:

`divide file into N chunks
   for each chunk
      hash(word)++;
   maxHeap(hash, 100)
merge all hash table and get the final top 100.`